How do i activate a python envrinment and run a python command in a shell script on ubuntu VM
I am able to run the script below on a remote server running on ubuntu 22.04. However, the same script on my ubuntu 22.04 VM running as a guest on Windows cannot run. Running the script on the terminal with "python script.py" runs without error, with python environment activated manually. Here is what I have tried so far
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/home/zmumba/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

eval "$(/home/zmumba/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
/home/zmumba/anaconda3/bin/conda run -n py12 python /home/zmumba/DA/Dekad_Progs/Programs/09_RiskMap.py

This runs fine on the remote server
On my VM, I get the error below
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

"conda install geopandas gives
# All requested packages already installed.

Then I added (from some posts), just before the command
source /home/zmumba/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate py12

Same geopandas error
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Have you read this? https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html


We strongly recommend to either install everything from the defaults channel, or everything from the conda-forge channel. Ending up with a mixture of packages from both channels for the dependencies of GeoPandas can lead to import problems. See the conda-forge section on using multiple channels for more details.

If you installed both, uninstall both then install one.

If Anaconda doesn't work, try with pip (after uninstalling the Anaconda version(s)) required -
pip install numpy pandas shapely pyproj pyogrio pyproj packaging

If you want optional dependencies, install them now optional -

fiona (optional; slower alternative to pyogrio)
psycopg (optional; for PostGIS connection)
psycopg2 (optional; for PostGIS connection - older version of psycopg library)
GeoAlchemy2 (optional; for writing to PostGIS)
geopy (optional; for geocoding)
pointpats (optional; for advanced point sampling)

For plotting optional:

matplotlib (>= 3.5.0)
fmapclassify (>= 2.4.0)
folium (for interactive plotting)

then required
pip install geopandas


If those don't work, try installing from Github -
git clone https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git
cd geopandas
pip install .


Try uninstalling python and conda and installing them again. Refer to the Uninstalling conda section of https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/install/linux.html. Uninstalling python depends on how you installed it. I recommend installing python3 if you don't have it installed instead as Python 2 is out of support.

If all of these don't work, consider creating a new VM and transferring your data to it.

Thanks for all this guidance. let me have a try.
